# Drupal 7 - Webform doesnt send SOME emails

Tags: drupal-7

I've created a contact webform. It works perfect, but it happens something strange: it doesn't send any email if the message is:

> "Nam ipsum libero, ultricies id tristique varius, vehicula feugiat
>   metus. Quisque consectetur metus at sem sagittis vitae pulvinar tortor
>   tempor. Fusce varius, odio ut consectetur hendrerit, nulla mi
>   elementum tortor, ac ullamcorper ante dolor id tellus. Vestibulum nunc
>   libero, venenatis eget luctus nec, tempus sed ligula. Phasellus
>   vestibulum rutrum nibh non imperdiet. Aliquam semper condimentum
>   tellus in placerat. Nullam sit amet ipsum eget lacus congue hendrerit
>   vel sodales turpis! Suspendisse ullamcorper velit et dui consectetur
>   scelerisque. Nam vestibulum tellus et magna porttitor sed porttitor
>   erat accumsan. In fermentum venenatis ligula, vel varius mi cursus
>   quis. Aenean varius fermentum libero eu luctus. Nunc quis dignissim
>   nunc! Ut adipiscing aliquet rutrum! Praesent nulla arcu, viverra vel
>   euismod sit amet, dictum vitae urna. Nam sit amet tortor ut augue
>   tempor feugiat quis vulputate ante."

this is a copy-pasted dummy message from a firefox extension. 
if i copy this messagge into the form, webform says that the messagge has been sent, but no emails arrive to my gmail account (spam folder checked; waited one hour)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the log of the outgoing mail server, as well as the Drupal db log.

If nothing was found, I would install the [SMTP](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module, and signup with a free SMTP service like [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) for 2 reasons.

1) You can determine if the issue is at the Drupal level vs an issue with the outgoing server you were using previously.

2) Mandrill does provide a log so you can confirm your email was sent.